# Got a confusing git error message

Tags: git, github

Got the following message which doesn't seem to be common online:

```
fatal: unknown style 'diff' given for 'merge.conflictstyle'
```

I have looked up styles for merge.conflictstyle and diff, and diff3 seem to be appropriate. I'm not sure where I can/should change this, but it's not allowing me to push any changes, as the branch is behind, because I can't pull due to the message above :(.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running

```
$ git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

and see if that works.

The issue is that you have an incorrect config option. That command will change it to the correct value, `diff3`.

Answer (score 4):

Run these 2 commands:

```
git config --global push.default upstream

git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

and then try to merge again, it may work now

Comment: including --global works for me. I don't need to run the first one though. Checkout works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`git config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), `diff` is not an acceptable style.  `merge` and `diff3` are the only ones it recognizes.  `merge` is the default... so perhaps, as mipadi mentioned, `diff3` is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

This git command should solve the issue:

```
git config merge.conflictstyle merge
```

Comment: From Review: Care to explain what the command does?