# git checkout results in fatal: unknown

Tags: git

I am trying to switch branches in Git so I ran `git checkout <branch name>`. It gives me this message:

> fatal: unknown style 'dif' given for 'merge.conflictstyle"

Then, I tried to configure the dif by using this statement: `git config merge.conflictstyle dif` but it is not working.

[image: screenshot of my terminal and me trying to switch branches]

Comment: "...but it's not working"... Please explain. Did the config command fail? Try editing the config file manually. E.g., `vi .git/config`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Got a confusing git error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981222/got-a-confusing-git-error-message)

Answer (score 3):

**`dif` is not a valid setting for `merge.conflictstyle`.** The only 2 valid settings are [**`merge`**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3e5524907b43337e82a24afbc822078daf7a868f/xdiff-interface.c#L320) and [**`diff3`**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3e5524907b43337e82a24afbc822078daf7a868f/xdiff-interface.c#L318).

So you can use one of these 2 commands:

```
git config merge.conflictstyle merge
git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

For a comparison of merge and diff3, see [**Git's documentation**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge-mergeconflictStyle).