# Can't switch between branches in git

Tags: git

I'm in the process of learning git. I had encountered this small issue while I am learning about branches. I created another branch and I called it sidebar. I tried to switch to this sidebar branch but it gives me this message:

```
$ git checkout sidebar
fatal: unknown style 'diff' given for 'merge.conflictstyle'
Barhome (master) new-git-project
```

Please explain to me how to fix this in order to be able to switch between branches ?!!

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Got a confusing git error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981222/got-a-confusing-git-error-message)

Answer (score 1):

Your `git` configuration is corrupted - or you're an old version of `git` with an incompatible configuration file.

See this QA: [Got a confusing git error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981222/got-a-confusing-git-error-message)

Comment: I have the most recent version of git. thanks I will check this QA.

Comment: Thank you. it worked.